# IdleTimeout in tcp server

Tags: go, tcp, tcpserver

I am working on a project in the Go language which includes *TCP server*. I am trying to implement an *idle timeout* on server sockets, but couldn't do it. The Go code I am using goes like this:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    startServer(6666, time.Duration(2)*time.Second)
}

func startServer(port int, deadline time.Duration) {
    // Listen for incoming connections.
    strPort := strconv.Itoa(port)
    l, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":"+strPort)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error listening:", err.Error())
        os.Exit(1)
    }
    // Close the listener when the application closes.
    defer l.Close()
    fmt.Println("Listening on port:" + strPort)
    for {
        // Listen for an incoming connection.
        conn, err := l.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Error accepting: ", err.Error())
            os.Exit(1)
        }

        fmt.Println("Got new connection")

        // Set read timeout
        conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(deadline))

        // Handle connections in a new goroutine.
        go handleRequest(conn)
    }
}

func handleRequest(conn net.Conn) {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(reader)

    for scanner.Scan() {
        fmt.Println(scanner.Bytes())
    }
}
```

I want it to **timeout** and close the connection after 2 seconds. Could anybody please tell me what I might be doing wrong. In order to test it, I am using a TCP client I wrote as Python scipt. The client code goes like this:

```
λ python
Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:54:25) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from socket import *
>>> c = socket(family=AF_INET, type=SOCK_STREAM)
>>> c.connect(('localhost', 6666))
```

I can always keep track of all the open connections, along with their last active time in some sort of data structure and launch a goroutine which periodically checks for time elapsed for every connection, closing the ones I haven't heard from in a while. But I wanted to utilize the built-in method `SetReadDeadline()` for the job.

Comment: I don't see what you're doing for an idle timeout here at all. The docs state: `An idle timeout can be implemented by repeatedly extending the deadline after successful Read or Write calls.`. Have you tried that?

Comment: I want it to timeout in the first place. Extending comes after this. The point is, its not closing my connection. **netstat -a** still shows active connections, even after 2 secs of connection.

Comment: Yes, so every Read (and/or Write) you set a new deadline.

Comment: But, I want to end `idle` connections. Using my python client, I want to simulate an idle connection (by sending nothing to the server). Now, Ideally, it should close the connection after 2 seconds, but it isn't.

Comment: Timeouts don't close connections. That's always up to you to properly call Close.

Comment: Is there some sort of callback I need to pass to close an idle connection? How can I handle idle timeout events?

Comment: The "callbacks" are the Read and Write calls themselves. I'll add an example of an idle timeout, but calling Close is always required. `c.settimeout(1)` and `c.recv(1)` in python isn't going to close the connection either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the `net` package documentation for `SetDeadline`, it states

> ```
>    // An idle timeout can be implemented by repeatedly extending
>    // the deadline after successful Read or Write calls.
> ```

You do this by creating your own `net.Conn` type to implement the call you want to have timeout. Since an idle connection would normally be waiting in `Read`, that is usually where you want to set the deadline.

```
type Conn struct {
    net.Conn
    idleTimeout time.Duration
}

func (c *Conn) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    err := c.Conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(c.idleTimeout))
    if err != nil {
        return 0, err
    }
    return c.Conn.Read(b)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But where are we closing connection?

Comment: That's up to your code. You close the connection when you're done with it. If the timeout was reached, the Read will return, and you'll have a deadline error.

Comment: Ok. Have you any idea of how can I make it work with `bufio.Scanner`? The code is written that way (using scanner). Can I make `scanner.Scan` call return after either read bytes or N seconds?

Comment: That's what this does already. The fact that you're using `bufio.Scanner` is beside the point.